# Battery Capacity and Charge Cycle

Tags: batteries

Can a lead acid battery whose capacity have been reduced to x mAh after some charge cycles be equivalent to a brand new smaller battery of x mAh if we assume both batteries have the same chemical properties?

Background:
I want to simulate the effect of reduction in battery capacity (due to aging battery) on some motors. My first intuition was to use new batteries with smaller capacities (e.g. 7Ah, 5Ah, 3Ah etc) from the same manufacturer. I know that using new batteries will not account for the build up of ESR in an aging battery but I am just wondering to what degree will my results be valid or invalid.

Comment: Well, the old one weighs more and weight often matters so not equivalent.

Comment: Interesting question, upvoted.

Comment: I'm also going with no, because part of the reason that the larger battery is reduced is because of increased ESR.  A new battery of smaller capacity will not have a higher ESR.

Comment: You need to precisely define what you mean by "equivalent to" as well as the phrase "same chemical properties".

Comment: I have added additional information for some context to the question. Hope this helps